# Implement pagination in Foursquare fetching tips apis

Tags: node.js, pagination, foursquare

I need to fetch tips for a given venue incrmentally as user scrolls through the list. For the api, https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/tips I can see limit and offset paramter to do this task but while fetching the tips if there are some new tips added to the foursquare venue page then it starts giving same tips again. How can I fix this ? Is this ecpected behaviour ? I have seen other social networks implementing startCursor and endCursor concept for this kind of pagination but not able to find similar thing in foursquare. Can anyone please tell me how can I avoid getting duplicate tips as new tips get added to a venue ?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you simply check createdAt property of the oldest of latest tips and start adding ones that are older? Hope you understand what i mean :)

Comment: That can be done but it's not a very elegant solution. It asks for an extra variable to keep on your side which will be used for adding older tips only. Shouldn't there be some cursor based pagination which can give you accurate results without any hack ?

Comment: They don't seem to have implemented such feature. So i guess it's up to you. It's 1 variable to compare createdAt property against and 1 if statement, that doesn't seem to be to much to do.